# How to show code external JavaScript in alert?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

How to show code external JavaScript in `alert` or anywhere because is value of variable `s_code`

```js
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
     newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
     newscript.async = true;
     newscript.src = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js?'+Math.random();
     s_code = newscript.toString();
     alert(s_code);
})();
```

Only using plain JavaScript without external library.

Comment: You might need to use AJAX for this.

Comment: The source code isn't made accessible through the script element (unless it's inline). You'd need to make a separate request for the file contents via Ajax, though you'll then have to contend with the same-origin policy.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, may give an example code?

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski, if it should be in line before being displayed can be converted to base64, is it possible?

Comment: @JasaPembuatWebsiteMurah I know it works using jQuery, pure JS I am not so good at.

Comment: @JasaPembuatWebsiteMurah [MDN's "Using XMLHttpRequest"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) should get you started with Ajax. – And, I'm not sure how base64 would help, other than to move the problem server-side. This seems likely to also prevent the file from being cached, defeating the benefits of using a CDN.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, If it must use jquery maybe I can use for a while before I find a way to plain javascript. is there any example code?

Comment: @JasaPembuatWebsiteMurah See my answer. Accept if it works.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, Thank you very much, I have tried and succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery's `$.get` you can do this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $.get("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js", function (res) {
    alert(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aahedi/y0v4kz3u/1/**

Comment: That only showing url is not the javascript code from url

Comment: You can change your answer to https://jsfiddle.net/aahedi/y0v4kz3u/1/ so I can make your post as an answer